# Is it possible to lambda function access to rds db via calling another rds db connector lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I know lambda function can both call another lambda function and access rds db. This is the case where both features are contained in one function.

This time, I want to create lambda A that manages accessing to rds db, and lambda B calls lambda A and access to rds db. (either by invoke lambda function directly or api url call)

I feel this can be done but couldn't find and hints but can't see anyone who have done my case.

### Added

For more specific scenario, I want lambda A to connect to my rds db using pymysql, returns pymysql.connect output. Lambda B calls lambda A, get pymysql.connect and put additional cursor and execute queries that I want.

The problem at the moment is when lambda is invoked, the output is in json and reading that json gives byte (or string by various methods). Beside, the original data type for pymysql.connect is <class 'pymysql.connections.Connection'>, therefore it does not work.

Comment: Your lambda A would act like a proxy to RDS. What's unclear about calling lambda A from B?

Comment: @Marcin Hi, I have just added detailed explanation of my current state. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done. The same AWS Lambda programming model would still apply. So you'd have to make your own API / model of how Lambda functions A and B would communicate with each other.